# Delete data by ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to delete items by ajax, so far i can get each item id but somehow when i click on delete button it just getting first item id.

## code

`controller`

```
public function delqtydisc(Request $request,$id)
 {
      $dele = QtyDiscount::find($id)->delete();
      return response()->json($dele);
 }
```

`route`

```
Route::post('/delqtydisc/{id}', 'QtyDiscountController@delqtydisc')->name('delqtydisc');
```

`script`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addnewqtydiscmsgsave").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //this adds new items to database (no issue here)
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('admin/addnewqtydisc') }}",
        data: {
          '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
          'product_id': $('#product_id').val(),
          'amount': $('#amount').val(),
          'min': $('.min').val(),
          'max': $('.max').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $('#addnewqtydiscmsg').empty();
          $('#addnewqtydiscmsg').append('<span class="text-success">Discount created successfully.</span>');

          var $tr = $('<tr/>');
          $tr.append($('<td/>').html(data.min));
          $tr.append($('<td/>').html(data.max));
          $tr.append($('<td/>').html(data.amount));

          // This adds delete button to my table
          $tr.append($('<td/>').html("<button class='qtyitemid btn btn-xs btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' type='button'>Delete this</button>"));

          $('.list-order tr:last').before($tr);

          $("#min").val('');
          $("#max").val('');
          $("#amount").val('');

          // From this part delete function adds

          $('.qtyitemid').on('click', function() {
            e.preventDefault();
              var QtyitemID = $('.qtyitemid').data('id');
              console.log(QtyitemID);
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: '{{ url('admin/delqtydisc') }}/'+encodeURI(QtyitemID),
                  data: {
                      '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                      'id': QtyitemID
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                      $('#addnewqtydiscmsg').empty();
                      $('#addnewqtydiscmsg').append('<span class="text-danger">Discount deleted successfully.</span>');
                  }
              });
          });
          // end of delete fuction
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

> PS: I commented each part of my JavaScript code that I thought should
>   bring your attention
>   `// This adds delete button to my table` and `// From this part delete function adds`

## Error

when I hit delete button I get 3 results (if i have 3 inputs) in my network, first one return `true` the other 2 return

```
"message": "Call to a member function delete() on null",
```

Any idea?

## Update

with code below my problem is solved some how, the only issue is remained is that i still get my row id's multiple. `e.g.` when i delete `id=1` network show it one time but when after that i delete `id=2` network shows two times `id=2`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addnewqtydiscmsgsave").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('admin/addnewqtydisc') }}",
        data: {
          '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
          'product_id': $('#product_id').val(),
          'amount': $('#amount').val(),
          'min': $('.min').val(),
          'max': $('.max').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $('#addnewqtydiscmsg').empty();
          $('#addnewqtydiscmsg').append('<span class="text-success">Discount created successfully.</span>').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut();

          var $tr = $("<tr id='" + data.id + "'>");
          $tr.append($('<td>').html(data.min));
          $tr.append($('<td>').html(data.max));
          $tr.append($('<td>').html(data.amount));
          $tr.append($('<td>').html("<button class='qtyitemid btn btn-xs btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' type='button'>Delete this</button>"));
          $('.list-order tr:last').before($tr);

          $("#min").val('');
          $("#max").val('');
          $("#amount").val('');
          //delete item
          $('.qtyitemid').on('click', function() {
            e.preventDefault();
              var QtyitemID = $(this).data('id');
              console.log(QtyitemID);
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: '{{ url('admin/delqtydisc') }}/'+encodeURI(QtyitemID),
                  data: {
                      '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                      'id': QtyitemID
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                      $('#addnewqtydiscmsg').empty();
                      $('#addnewqtydiscmsg').append('<span class="text-danger">Discount deleted successfully.</span>').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                      $('table tr#'+QtyitemID+'').remove();
                  }
              });
          });
          //
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

> PS: basically most of my problem is solved i'm just looking for answer
>   to avoid this multiple id in network.

Comment: You appear to be adding a new set of event handlers every time you click on your `#addnewqtydiscmsgsave` element. Don't do that. Instead, use event delegation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @mafortis: I think you need to reload the page after deleting an item. Use this in `success: function(data) {`: `location.reload();` Hope it'll fixed your issue!!

Comment: @mafortis: Is that helped??

Comment: @HirenGohel no bro, i have made some changes base on `aceraven777` answer.  it is working now but still i get id of each item twice. (i will update my question)

Answer (score 1):

The error occurred in your `qtyitemid` on click event. Specifically this line: `var QtyitemID = $('.qtyitemid').data('id');`
This JS code will always return the data of the first `qtyitemid` class. You must use the keyword `this` to determine what element is clicked. This code hopefully fix the problem:

```
    $('.qtyitemid').on('click', function() {
            e.preventDefault();
              var QtyitemID = $(this).data('id');
              console.log(QtyitemID);
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: '{{ url('admin/delqtydisc') }}/'+encodeURI(QtyitemID),
                  data: {
                      '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                      'id': QtyitemID
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                      $('#addnewqtydiscmsg').empty();
                      $('#addnewqtydiscmsg').append('<span class="text-danger">Discount deleted successfully.</span>');
                  }
              });
          });
```

Comment: hi, that seem to working (at least getting all my id's) here I share screenshot of the error i'm facing https://ibb.co/fTHkDz

Comment: @mafortis, so far I detected 2 problems in your code. 1. After deleting the item you didn't remove the item row from the table, the item still exists on the table so clicking it again will pop an error because its already been deleted. 2. In your controller, before deleting the item, you must first check if the item exists.

Comment: for issue one i was waiting to fix this issue first, for second issue i think `find()` will do the job of returning item if exist isn't it?

Comment: so what do you think the issue is now?

Comment: I already told you the 2 problems in your code. You need to fix that.